# InfoPath form has Multiple Selection List Box that checks all items instead of just one

Tags: 2010, development, infopath

In InfoPath 2010, I have a Multiple-Selection List Box that uses an external data source to populate the check box items. This data source is an xml document that gets dynamically populated in the code behind in the On_Load method from a SharePoint list with the Title field and a Check box field. I have three items in this list and all three show up in the Multiple-Selection List Box. But when I check one of the check boxes, all three of them become checked, and vice-versa. I suspect this is because my Multiple-Selection List box is bound to a single repeating field.

Any suggestions on how I can check just one item in this Multiple-Selection List Box and not have every other item get checked as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Remove your C# code behind and use Sharepoint list column Title to fill items of Multiple Selection List Box instead of XML file and check box column of sharepoint list](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/24034/83231.aspx#83231).

[image: MSLB_Dynamically_Updateable_Items Sharepoint List]

Fig.1. MSLB_Dynamically_Updateable_Items Sharepoint List

[image: Fig.2. Multiple Selection List Box in Infopath Designer 2010]

Fig.2. Multiple Selection List Box in Infopath Designer 2010

[image: Fig.3. Running browser form with MSLB in client/filler]

Fig.3. Running browser form with MSLB in client/filler

[image: Fig.4. Enter URL. First Step of Data Connection Wizard]
Fig.4. Enter URL. First Step of Data Connection Wizard

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. This solution works on my machine, but since I am developing this on a different server farm with different site collections, I don't know how to connect to the MSLB_Dynamically_Updateable_Items Sharepoint List. Is there a way to I can manually enter a site collection URL (not on the current Server Farm) or change the URL after the form has been published?

Comment: Yes, you will be able change it in Data Source (Add... ) of MSLB properties, see Fig.2,  at first step of Data Connection Wizard. You should republish once the template though